# How to use Tomcat 8 in Intellij?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

When I want to run the demo, web page is displaying following error,why?
Is it the problem of versions? I'm running Apache Tomcat/8.0.14, springframework 4.1.1.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
Unable to compile class for JSP:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [42] in the generated java file:   

[/home/cuifugang/.IntelliJIdea13/system/tomcat/Tomcat_8_0_14_springMVCFirst/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/pages/hello_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:172)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 logs.
```

Comment: I've seen a similar problem once with Tomcat 8.0, Spring 4.1.1 and IntelliJ. Try deleting your IntelliJ project files and re-importing the project (from for example your Maven `pom.xml` file). (That solved the problem for me).

Comment: Check event log, you have probably missed a message invited you to download required libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have older `servlet.jar` in your `WEB-INF/lib`. Your build process is probably incorrect. This issue is also described here:  https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57020

Comment: ok.thank you very much!after i change to tomcat 7 is ok

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It works after I set the scope of servlet-api to "provided" in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yeah,thank you@Qingzi